# constructor overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I have different constructor of same class and I want to call them with same object.
Is it possible?

Such as:

```
class Calcy
{
  int a,b,d;
  double c;

  Calcy()
  {
    c=a+b;
    System.out.println("Ans -> "+c);
  }

  Calcy(int a,int b)
  {
    c=a/b;
    d=a%b;
    System.out.println("Ans -> "+c+d);
  }   

  Calcy(double a,double b)
  {
    c=a*b;
    System.out.println("Ans -> "+c);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Calcy **cal** = new Calcy(7,6);
    Calcy **cal** = new Calcy(5.3,6.1);
    Calcy **cal** = new Calcy();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An object can be constructed only once. However, constructors can call other methods, including other constructors. However, once the constructor returns, that's it. If that's a problem, maybe you are putting code in the constructor that ought to be in a method, or in an 'initialize' method?

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many `Calcy` objects as you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Calcy cal = new Calcy(7,6);
cal = new Calcy(5.3,6.1);
cal = new Calcy(); // What does this mean to calculate nothing?
}
```

If you want to preserve the state of the previous calculation, simply store multiple instances.

If you want to feed one Calcy into the next object, simply expand your constructor to take a Calcy as input, i.e.:

```
  Calcy(Calcy a,int b)
  {
    c=a.getC() / b;
    d=a.getD() % b; // Guessing this is what you want? 
    System.out.println("Ans -> "+c+d);
  }
```

Note that you'll need to make accessors for c and d.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a constructor is variable initialization.Ofcourse you can have more than one constructor within the same class.Each time you call a constructor a different object is created. But if you want to perform some operations on the variables its better to use methods.Even methods can be overloaded and you can call them on the same object. for eg.,

```
int add(int x,int y){
   return (x+y);
}

float add(float x,float y){
   return (x+y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create duplicate object:

```
Calcy **cal** = new Calcy(7,6);
Calcy **cal** = new Calcy(5.3,6.1);
Calcy **cal** = new Calcy();
```

But you can create many object with other constructors or sign a object with its:

```
Calcy **cal1** = new Calcy(7,6);
Calcy **cal2** = new Calcy(5.3,6.1);
Calcy **cal3** = new Calcy();
```

or
    Calcy **cal** = new Calcy(7,6);
    **cal** = new Calcy(5.3,6.1);
    **cal** = new Calcy();

The Constructor:

```
  Calcy()
  {
    c=a+b;
    System.out.println("Ans -> "+c);
  }
```

is not correct, you need init values.